# How to delete skype chat history?

Tags: skype

Is there any way to clear my Skype chat history in Fedora.My skype version is 4.3.0.37 and the fedora version is Version 3.14.2.

Comment: How is this question security related? Please read the [help](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

For single chats, go to history, you right click on a conversation and delete it via the popup menu. For global, go to Tools > Options > Privacy and click on Delete All Chat History

As an aside, skype keeps its data in an sqlite database which you can access directly. Details for similar poking about the database can be found here: http://www.huesler-informatik.ch/2014/08/29/exporting-skype-conversations-on-osx/
which I found useful when I was trying to import contacts from one account to another.